# The read method on the inotify descriptor does not return

Tags: c++, c, file-descriptor, inotify, file-monitoring

My program monitors changes on files using [`inotify(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify)

```
fd = inotify_init();
inotify_add_watch (fd, "./test.txt", IN_ALL_EVENTS);
//start forever monitor
while(true){
       ssize_t len, i = 0;
       char action[81+FILENAME_MAX] = {0};
       char buff[BUFF_SIZE] = {0};
       len = read (fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
       while (i < len) {
           //process event
           i += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + pevent->len;
       }
}
```

The problem is that the read function only return several times for the firt changes in the monitor file (ACCESS, OPEN, MODIFY events). Unfortunately after that, the read function does not return any more although there a lot of changes in the monitored file.

However, If I reset the inotify descriptor and readd the monitered file agains, ==> the read function always return.

```
//start forever monitor
while(true){
       ssize_t len, i = 0;
       char action[81+FILENAME_MAX] = {0};
       char buff[BUFF_SIZE] = {0};
       fd = inotify_init();
       inotify_add_watch (fd, "./test.txt", IN_ALL_EVENTS);
       len = read (fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
       while (i < len) {
           //process event
           i += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + pevent->len;
       }
}
```

Could you guys help me explain this error. Thanks so much!!!!!!

Comment: man inotify and check event: IN_IGNORED. Please also describe what operations are done on "./test.txt"

Comment: @xgwang: this event is sent by the kernel when this file is deleted. So, what should I do with this event to continue to monitor this file?? I'm duying for your answer!

Comment: monitor it and when this event happens, just use `inotify_add_watch` to add the watch again on the "same file" (it is actually a different file if you look into filesystem)

Comment: @xgwang: It've tried to add inotify_add_watch("test.txt") when receiving the event IN_IGNORED, but I still got the error "No such files or directory". I don't get it, why does this file still exist in the file system (I can see in using ls command in linux), but I inotify_add_watch return error?

Comment: @Sam Miller: it's large enough for hundreds events. I feel suspicious about the BUFF_SIZE and check the queue of the system call "read" before call it ==> the buffer (with BUFF_SIZE) is 100% enough for reading.

Comment: @khanhhh89 i doubt there may be sth. wrong with file access or file path. Try `access`, `realpath` and `stat` (man these syscalls) to check you have the right permission, the right file path for `test.txt`

Comment: if you are deleting and recreating test.txt then what xgwang said is correct, the file is actually a "different" file.  you will get the "no such file or directory" possibly because a race condition exists: the file is removed and you get the event before the file can be recreated. try also monitoring the directory where the file exists and you'll see the IN_CREATE.